# Is it possible to print to a Zebra belt printer from a web app?

Tags: asp.net, refactoring, smartphone, zebra-printers

The app I am maintaining is, to put it mildly, long in the tooth and badly in need of a rewrite. It is a Compact Framework app that runs on a Windows CE device, using .NET 1.1 and Visual Studio 2003 (XP Mode to develop). IOW, it's a royal pain in the donkey to maintain. There is also a hue and cry from the users for something more modern.

In considering a replacement, I would like to go the web app route. But the big question/potential dealbreaker: Is it possible to print to Zebra belt printers from a web app on a smartphone?

The intent would be for the users to access the web app/site from a device such as a smartphone or "phablet" that would be connected to the belt printer. Is this feasible, or pie-in-the-sky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new mobile printers (QLn and iMZ) [has the ability to communicate over web sockets](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/cloud-connect.html). So if you can write your web app and incorporate web socket standards, the printer will connect to the printer over wifi to the server (even thru firewalls) bidirectionally.  If you can't do this, Zebra also provides a [Windows Mobile SDK](http://www.zebra.com/us/en/products-services/software/link-os/link-os-sdk.html) and it's pretty easy to hook into a winMo app.

Comment: "the printer will connect to the printer" -- sounds like an endless loop, or at least a feedback loop. So give me some feedback: did you mean "printer to device"?

Comment: And I know this wasn't part of my original question, but we also need to support other printer brands; would the link you provided allow that, or is it a Zebra-specific solution?

Comment: With websockets, the printer initiates the connection in order to get thru the firewall. (So if your server was on an amazon instance, the server wouldn't know how to get to a local wifi printer with a local 192.168.x address. So the server would have to accept the connection and then manage it

Comment: The connection parts of the sdk (open/close/read/write) *should* work with any peripheral. But there's a lot of proprietary zebra stuff on top of that. But if all you want to do is send bytes to a printer, the sdk should work for you

Comment: We have a network of ZD420s connected to a Tomcat VM with a custom rest API exposed that our Azure webapp has used daily for the last 6 months with no issues.

NB: Azure doesn't support open websockets in webapps that will accept custom privately-signed SSL like the printer requires so you're basically forced to put it on a VM.

I didn't like having a giant binary blob for their library but the .WAR file is easily decompilable if you want to have your own Java for the entire implementation.